# how to build jdk11 from openJDK source code

Tags: java, java-11

how to build JRE/JDK from openJDK source?

Which repository we have to use jdk11 or jdk 11u ? What are pros and cons for using it?

I am trying to build jdk on platform : Red Hat 7.5. & Target platforms are : Amazon Linux EC2 and Red Hat 7.5

Comment: Hi - AFAIK jdk11 is now on github: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u-dev/
The page on http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk-updates/ is a bit outdated as it still talks about the mercurial repository.

Comment: Building a software can be different depending on the platform you are building it(and in case you are cross-compiling the target platform als plays a role). Therefore you should edit your post and give more details on the used OS (and e.g. used distribution in case of Linux).

Answer (score 2):

> how to build JRE/JDK from openJDK source

There are comprehensive instructions in the following document on the OpenJDK site:

- [Building the JDK](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/build/doc/building.html)

These instructions explain where to get the current sources from; i.e. from the GitHub repos.

> Which repository we have to use jdk11 or jdk 11u ? What are pros and cons for using it?

The jdk11 is the original Java 11 GA release.  The jdk11u is Java 11 with all of the patches.  The pros and cons should be self-evident.  The above build instructions document recommends that you use jdk11u.

> I am trying to build jdk on platform : Red Hat 7.5. & Target platforms are : Amazon Linux EC2 and Red Hat 7.5

There are instructions for building on generic Linux in the above document.  They should produce build artifacts that work on both of those platforms.